# PCA with Catagorical Variable in R

Tags: r, pca

Is there any Package for PCA for data having Categorical variable ?

Comment: Try out the PCAmixdata package in R

Comment: Short answer no, but there are other forms of dimension reduction that may be of use: [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont) and [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215404/is-there-factor-analysis-or-pca-for-ordinal-or-binary-data) for discussions

Answer (score 2):

No, there aren't.  I wish there were.  It would make life a lot easier.

A categorical variable is just that:  a category.  It might be represented by a number but it cannot be treated like one.  For example, if you have a list of cars with their colors, and the colors are denoted this way:

`1 = red
2 = blue
3 = green`

you can't really work with them as numbers.  You can't say that blue is the average color, for instance, because the average of 1 + 2 + 3 is 2.

What you can do is create dummy variables, usually a 0 and 1, which then describe the category.  In our example:

`0 = not red
1 = red`

You can then create dummies for the other colors along similar lines:

`0 = not blue
1 = blue`

and

`0 = not green
1 = green`

This can be done across different columns to make things easier.  It's all part of the mungification of data, getting it into shape so you can run an analysis.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Any dimensionality reduction technique suppose you are dealing with algebraic values, and categorical variables do not have such meaning.

If you have a categorical variable which indicate - as example - families' pets in one of (cat, dog, red fish) mapped to (0, 1, 2), you simply cannot say that the distance between cat and dog is equal to one, because those categories do not lie in an algebraic space.

So, in those cases, you do the one-hot encoding of the variables, a.k.a. dummyfication. Then you can safely apply PCA, or any other dimensionality reduction technique.